# Clang++ Compiles, but doesn't run

Tags: compiling, c++, clang

I try to compile a program by typing (lets assume here I'm cd'd into the directory) 
`clang++ file_name.cpp`. It compiles and should autorun, but it doesn't, and just ends the event, and opens the terminal back for input. I see a file named 'a.out' in the folder directory. And if I type
`clang++ file_name.cpp`, nothing happens, and I am back in the terminal. If I type 
`clang++ a.out.cpp`, the compiler says it can't find the file, and the compiler closes. I tried to see if clang is properly installed, and it is. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: "... and should autorun".  This is incorrect, `clang++ file_name.cpp` compiles the program, it doesn't run it.  By default it generates an executable name `a.out`.  If you want to run it, type `./a.out`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A compiler like `clang++` only does compiling of the source code.  In your case, it creates the executable file `a.out` (since you didn't explicitly tell it to use some other output filename using the `-o` option).  The compiler will not automatically run the resulting executable.  These things also holds true for `g++` (the GNU C++ compiler) as well as for both the `clang` and `gcc` C compilers (and most other compilers of languages requiring compilation).

To run the executable, issue the command

```
./a.out
```

at the shell's command prompt.

To give the executable another name than the traditional default of `a.out`, use something like

```
clang++ -o myprog file_name.cpp
```

to create `myprog` from the sources in `file_name.cpp`.

---

Given the sources in the single file `file_name.cpp`, `make` can also be used to compile the sources into  the executable `file_name` using the command

```
make file_name
```

while in the same directory as the source code file (but only if the source code has been updated since `file_name` was last compiled).  This requires no `Makefile` to be present but will instead use implicit rules built into `make` for compiling C++ sources.

Use

```
CXX=clang++ make file_name
```

to explicitly use the `clang++` compiler.

For more on this, see the GNU `make` documentation about [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) (other implementations of `make`, e.g. on BSD systems, use similar implicit rules).

Comment: Thank you! In the past it was able to auto load it without my typing ./a.out

Comment: @TrevorHummer The `clang++` compiler has never been able to, as far as I know, automatically run the resulting executable, and I haven't worked with any compiler on Unix that have done so.